# Voting ranking with charts in foreach loop

Tags: php, graph, charts, ranking, rating

i have the result of a ranking script in a foreach loop, sorted by the number of votes. is there a way to visualize this with a chart/graph tool? the results are in a table, so each "project" has its own

```
<tr><td>project name</td><td>4</td></tr>
```

i want to display the number of votes eg. 4, in a row underneath the written result. and that for all other results too.

any advice?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Use something like [jpGraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/). You install the class and pass it data, and it displays a pretty graph for you.